# calculate overall rating as per multiple ratings selection

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I have list of hospitals in which users can rate on various topic from 10. Here I have 6 topics of ratings & is all working fine. I want to know how do I calculate & display average overall rating given by use. e.g. users have given (6,5,3,8,2,10) this rating to particular hospitals then average of all this should be calculate. With my current code I am able to calculate average rating on any one topic but how do I calculate overall?

Code

```
If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
            Dim dt As DataTable = Me.GetData("SELECT IFNULL(AVG(Rate), 0) AverageRating, COUNT(Rate) RatingCount FROM ratings")
            Rating1.CurrentRating = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(0)("AverageRating"))
            lblRatingStatus.Text = String.Format("{0} Users have rated.", dt.Rows(0)("RatingCount"))

            average.Text = String.Format("Average Rating {0}", dt.Rows(0)("AverageRating"))
        End If
```

I tried to put queries like this in which I tried to calcukate two topics average rating (behaviour, treatment) but it gives syntax error

```
SELECT IFNULL(AVG(`behaviour`, `treatment`), 0) AverageRating, COUNT(`behaviour`, `treatment`) RatingCount FROM ratings
```

Comment: Show your `ratings` table with some example data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can try something like below,

```
Select (rating1+rating2+rating3)/3 from tablename
```